# http://localhost/5000 not working in docker flask

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

can't open file '/web/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
exited with code 2

NOTE: Tried all similar problems solution posted, did not work.

No matter what I do, not able to get http://localhost/5000 to work. Even if the above error goes away by removing volume and command from docker-container.

Below is docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    command: python /web/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - './users:/usr/src/app'
 
    ports:
      - 5000:5000 
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
```

Below is Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.5-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

BELOW IS manage.py:

```
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
from project import app
cli = FlaskGroup(app)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

BELOW IS **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return jsonify(hello="world")
```

Below is the structure:

The ones marked in red appeared when I ran this command: docker-compose build
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiIZS.png)

Comment: Dont you need to expose the port in you dockerfile e.g `EXPOSE 5000`. I am also a little confused about the port `8000` isn't your server running on 8000 and not 5000?

Comment: It's `http://localhost:5000/`, not `http://localhost/5000` (which is equal to `http://localhost:80/5000`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes to do.

The cli command in your `docker-compose.yml` file needs to be:

```yaml
    command: python /usr/src/app/manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
```

There the command name is `run` and not `runserver`. Also the `host` ip to bind and `port` to listen are configured as different command options.

Also the configured port mapping for the service needs to map to the container port from the command:

```yaml
    ports:
      - 5000:8000
```

In your `manage.py` module, [`FlaskGroup`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#command-line-interface) should be provided `create_app` option which is factory not the app instance.
You can implement this as a lambda function.

```py
cli = FlaskGroup(create_app=(lambda:app))
```

**Edit**

The source files are not mounted in the container volume that why you're getting "no such file `manage.py`".

You need to mount your source files in the container volume under `/usr/src/app`.

```
volumes:
  - './web:/usr/src/app'
```

Comment: command: python /usr/src/app/manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
I did try that initially, I actually want the port to be 5000, it wasnt working still so tried different steps.                                                                                                         command: python /usr/src/app/manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
cli = FlaskGroup(create_app=(lambda:app))
ports: - 5000:5000  now changed these and checked     http://localhost:5000/ too, still get error no such file manage.py and the link doesnt run.